# Is the C++ ostream at the start of a line?

Tags: c++, position, ostream

In C++, how do I detect if my `std::ostream os` is at the start of a line, in other words (I think) the most recent thing written to `os` is either `os<<'\n'` or `os<<std::endl()`, or else nothing has yet been written to `os`?

At first glance, this sounds unnecessary, because I can just keep track of the state myself.  But a common scenario is the following, where keeping track would involve altering every `os<<thing` statement which could possibly be called from the `try` block, in a very unnatural way.

```
try {
  do_something_which_writes_to(std::cout);
}
catch(const My_error&error) {
  print_a_newline_if_necessary(std::cout);
  std::cout<<error<<"\n";
}
```

(In reality, of course, we want to write `error` to `std::cerr` but that usually gets mixed in with `std::cout` unless one of them is redirected, so we still want to terminate the `std::cout` line before printing to `std::cerr`. I have deliberately simplified the example to avoid this distraction.)

You might imagine that `os.tellp()` would be the answer, but `tellp()` seems to work only on `std::ofstream`. For me at least, `std::cout.tellp()` always returns `-1`, indicating that it is not supported.

Comment: `cout` might not even know what was written to the buffer. It could have been written to the underlying media and be long gone. You can get away with it when working with a file because the file's (probably) not going anywhere before you close it. Serial port, network socket, or whatever backs the command console, Crom only knows where the data went and how long ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least as I'm reading things, what you really want isn't the ability to get the position in the current line. Rather, what you really want is to be able to print something that is guaranteed to be at the start of a line--the current line if the immediately previous character was a newline (and, I'd guess also if it was a carriage return), but otherwise print a newline, then whatever follows.

Here's some code to do that:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class linebuf : public std::streambuf
{
    std::streambuf* sbuf;
    bool            need_newline;

    int sync() {
        return sbuf->pubsync();
    }
    int overflow(int c) {
        switch (c) { 
            case '\r':
            case '\n': need_newline = false;
                break;
            case '\v':
                if (need_newline) { 
                    need_newline = false;
                    return sbuf->sputc('\n');
                }
                return c;
            default:
                need_newline = true;
                break;
        }
        return sbuf->sputc(c);
    }
public:
    linebuf(std::streambuf* sbuf)
        : sbuf(sbuf)
        , need_newline(true)
    {}
    std::streambuf *buf() const { return sbuf; }
    ~linebuf() { sync(); }
};

class linestream : public std::ostream {
    linebuf buf;
    std::ostream &os;
public:
    linestream(std::ostream& out)
        : buf(out.rdbuf())
        , std::ios(&buf)
        , std::ostream(&buf)
        , os(out)
    {
        out.rdbuf(&buf);
    }
    ~linestream() { os.rdbuf(buf.buf()); }
};

void do_stuff() { 
    std::cout << "\vMore output\v";
}

int main() {
    { 
       linestream temp(std::cout);

        std::cout << "\noutput\n";
        std::cout << "\voutput";
        do_stuff();
        std::cout << "\voutput\n";
        std::cout << "\voutput\v";
    }
    std::cout << "\voutput\v";
}
```

Since it's almost never used otherwise, I've hijacked the vertical tab (`'\v'`) to signify the special behavior.

To use it, you simply create a temporary object of type `linestream` (sorry, I'm too tired to think of a good name right now), passing it an ostream object that will get the new behavior when a `\v` gets written to it. When that temporary object goes out of scope, the stream will be restored to its original behavior (I doubt anybody uses `\v` often enough to care, but who knows maybe somebody care--it's mostly just a side effect of cleaning up after itself anyway).

In any case, the special behavior remains in place when `do_stuff` is called, so it's not just local to the function where the local `linestream` object is created, or anything like that--once it's created, the special behavior remains in effect until it's destroyed.

One other point though: when/if you mix output from `cout` and `cerr`, this won't help much. In particular, neither will be at all aware of the other's state. You'd probably much need some hooks into the output terminal (or something on that order) to be able to deal with that, since output redirection is normally handled by the OS, so inside the program there's no way to even guess whether data written to `cout` and `cerr` are going to the same place or not.

Comment: Thank you so much for the class - that's a whole lot of work you've put in, and I've always been scared to delve into `std::streambuf` and its friends. By the way, I think the constructor might want to initialize `need_newline(false)`. But I'll wait in case there's a way to use the existing `std::ostream` API before marking this as the accepted answer.

Comment: @AdamChalcraft: Whether it should initially be true or false depends on what you want (maybe I didn't read carefully enough but I didn't see a clear definition of what you wanted at the beginning of the output. But in any case, you see to understand how to make it do what you want...

Comment: As for the `cout` and `cerr` thing, I agree there's no perfect answer, but I'm happy with a `{std::cout<<"\v"; std::cerr<<"\verror\n";}` solution. At worst, it writes and extra `'\n'` to `std::cout` in a situation where an error has occurred anyway.